# Execute python script with java function

Tags: java, python

I need to execute  python script within java function. I tried something but it's not working properly

Here is my code:

```
private static void generateReport() {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python ReportGeneration/reportGeneration.py");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }

}
```

This is my run.sh file:

```
CLASSPATH=.:target/classes:target/filter-4.0.0-M20-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"
FULL_EXPERIMENT_DURATION_MINUTES=2
WARM_UP_PERIOD_MINS=1
java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH  yyy.xxx.sample.common.benchmarks.filter.Benchmark $FULL_EXPERIMENT_DURATION_MINUTES $WARM_UP_PERIOD_MINS
```

When i try to run python script alone (using python reportGeneration.py command in commandline) it gives me an output but when i try to execute it with java function it's not giving any output? is there any error in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does your script have execute permissions?

Comment: you could also try: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python ReportGeneration/reportGeneration.py");`

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre  Thank you. your suggestion cleared my error. But python script is not producing expected results. my python script perfectly working fine when i tried to execute it individually

Comment: then it is a problem of current directory. [edit] your question to show how you run your script (without the java layer)

Comment: done sir i edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jython library](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) to run python scripts inside java code.

For example:

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    initializeJython();
    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

    interpreter.exec("print \"Hello World\"");
    //interpreter.execfile(); // You can also execute script from a file.
}

private static void initializeJython() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("python.console.encoding", "UTF-8");
    props.put("python.import.site", "false"); //Jython doesn't work for me without setting this property to false.

    PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), props, new String[0]);
}

}
```

If your project is maven based you can add jython dependency like this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```